# When yarn is used to create React app only node_modules, package.json, yarn.lock is formed

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I want to build a React App by installing it with yarn.
So these are the steps I have used so far to install the react app:

```
1.I have installed nodejs
```

After installation I used this command to install the react app:

```
2.yarn create react-app my-app
```

After successful installation of `my-app` I found out three things in it:

```
1.node_modules
2.package.json
3.yarn.lock
```

But the problem I am facing right now is that I don't know how I can start my app. So please guide me what I need to do next.

Comment: Can’t you just cd my-app then yarn start https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Comment: it is showing command 'start' not found

Comment: how command can start i dont have index.html and index.js

Comment: Yes i have gone through that link but i don't understand what to do the next.